# Getting 403 Error when I try to access, but I am not seeing Elevated access option in Developer Portal any help appreciated

Tags: twitter

403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits.
message - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here:
code - 453

I have also tried for V2 got this error:
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal

I have tried to creating Developer Account on twitter and follow the steps as per the Twitter official document with different SDKs(Java). In fact I have tried with postman collection but no luck.